# getting address of pointer from function return value

Tags: c++, pointers

Let's say i have unbalanced binary tree data structure. After init() i have variable Node* root set to `NULL`
One of my method is trying to insert node in the tree

```
bool insertNode(Node ** currentNode, const string & key, int val)
{
    Node* newNode;

    if (*currentNode == NULL)
    {
        newNode = newNode(key,val);
        *currentNode = newNode;
        if(root==NULL) root = newNode;
        return true;
    } 
    if (key<*currentNode->getKey())
    {
        insertNode((Node **)&(*currentNode)->getLeft(), key, val); //error
    }
    if (key>*currentNode->getKey())
    {
        insertNode((Node **)&(*currentNode)->getRight(), key, val); //error
    }
    return false;
}

Node* getRoot() { return root; }
```

It is called

```
insertNode((Node **)&(tree.getRoot())); //error
```

Unfortunatelly compiler gives me errors

```
error: lvalue required as unary ‘&’ operand|
```

If i call fce insertNode with variable `Node* node` like this

```
Node* node = tree.getRoot(); 
insertNode((Node **)&node); //no error
```

It's without error.

Could you please explain me why?

EDIT:
After ravi's answer i realised that i've changed only copies of addresses.

To solve it i changed fce

```
Node** getRoot() { return  &root; }
```

Also member methods for Node

```
Node** getLeft()
{
  return &m_left;
}

Node** getRight()
{
    return &m_right;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
insertNode((Node **)&(tree.getRoot()));
```

This is because you cannot use return values of function returning built in types by value as an l-value.

Comment: Could you please explain it in more detail?

Comment: So, lets say a function is returning an int. " int func();". Using it as an l-value "func() = 4" doesn't makes sense as you are just trying to modify the temporary returned.

Comment: I think i get it now :) Is it because the return value (address of root) is just copy of it? So i would change later in next funtion another place in the memory?